# ARA Records Ansible: "No directory at: /home/user/.ara/server/www/static/"

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ara

I am facing this issue when I try to enter an [`ara`](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara) command:

```
cd ~
ara playbook list
```

Output:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:58: UserWarning: No directory at: /home/user/.ara/server/www/static/ 
> mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)

I am running this in [Ubuntu 20.04.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) LTS (Focal Fossa).

```
cd ~
which python3
```

Output:

> /usr/bin/python3

```
python3 --version
```

Output:

> Python 3.8.10

```
pip list | grep ara
```

Output:

> ara     1.6.1

```
pip list | grep django
```

Output:

> ```
> django-cors-headers    4.1.0
> django-filter          23.2
> django-health-check    3.17.0
> djangorestframework    3.14.0
> ```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is stating that there's no directory at `/home/user/.ara/server/www/static/`. This suggests that the Ara server is looking for static resources at that location, but it can't find them. This could be due to the directory not existing, or Ara not being configured correctly to find its static files.

Ara is a tool for visualizing and managing Ansible runs, and it has a server component that serves a web interface. The server component uses Django, a Python web framework, which in turn uses a system of static files for things like CSS, JavaScript, and images. When Django runs, it needs to know where these static files are located. The warning message is indicating that Django is looking for static files in the directory `/home/user/.ara/server/www/static/`, but it's not finding anything there.

Here's a potential solution you can try:

1. Check if the directory `/home/user/.ara/server/www/static/` exists. You can do this by running the command `ls /home/user/.ara/server/www/static/` in your terminal. If the directory doesn't exist, you will get a "No such file or directory" error.
2. If the directory doesn't exist, you need to create it. Run the command `mkdir -p /home/user/.ara/server/www/static/`. The `-p` option will create any necessary parent directories.
3. If the directory does exist, it's possible that Ara is not configured correctly to find its static files. According to the Ara documentation, you can specify the location of the static files with the `ARA_STATIC_ROOT` environment variable. Try setting this variable to the location where your static files are actually stored. For example, if your static files are in `/path/to/static/files/`, you would run `export ARA_STATIC_ROOT=/path/to/static/files/`.
4. After doing one of the above steps, try running the Ara command again.

Please replace `/home/user/` with the actual path if it is different in your case.

Comment: The directory doesn't exist. I created it and now I am not getting any issues. I was expecting that something else needed to be done appart from creating the directory. Thanks for your help

Comment: *Many* of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). 

If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds honestly, this looks like one of the most responsible users: despite many answers written in ChatGPT style (I don't say it was or was not used - I'm really lost here), most of them are correct from my own judging. This one is extremely verbose and resembles ChatGPT very much, though. Usually I use "complete nonsense written in very confident words" as a ChatGPT marker, and it clearly does not apply to answers by 70ny. I would recommend you to stop pursuing this user, looks like he either really does not use chatgpt or is skilled enough to keep only good AI-gen answers.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike I agree in principle -- This one is certainly "borderline".  When I saw this user's answers yesterday, I gave them a pass, but then several of them today gave me some concern.

Comment: I'm all in favor of [people using AI responsibly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710) on Stack, but currently the policy disallows that.  To me, responsible use includes citing/acknowledging its use (as should always be done when obtaining information from another source or site). However, we're in a weird "Don't ask; don't tell" policy where people  aren't allowed to even disclose when they using AI in any way, shape, or form. This is unfortunate, and I do hope the policy changes soon.

Comment: I'll add that having personally flagged more than 1,200 GPT answers (pre-strike, with only 12 declined flags), seeing more than 1,000 others that I didn't personally flag, chatting with several of the Mods, and seeing the actions, I feel that this user would *very likely* have been suspended pre-May 31st under the policy based on these recent answers, regardless of whether or not the answers were helpful.  That, as well, is likely unfortunate, so these "heads-up" messages are probably preferable ;-)

Comment: my 2 cents: I provided comments and motivations to my answers. If this is treated as GPT usage, okay, I'll just push the final solution. Just don't comment after with "explain it" please. Like on question 76542253 : how can you tell the first answer has not been created via GPT?

Comment: I know the advent of GPT gave everyone tools that were impossible prior to that. I've always enjoyed being here, both asking questions and receiving answers. Just make sure this "that's GPT" fear doesn't get out of control, as this can literally kill this wonderful place. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @70ny Re:[76542253](/a/76542253) - Having spent way too much time identifying (*likely*) GPT-assisted answers over the last few months, I have quite a few ways of spotting what appears to be GPT, but I don't divulge those publicly or people would just attempt to edit those indicators out of their answers. With any heuristics, of course, the more text that is available to analyze, the more likely it is to be identifiable.  I see very little indication in the answer (or other answers from the same user) you asked about that would indicate GPT usage.

Comment: On the other hand, you put something in one of your answers that is *very* rarely (perhaps never?) done by a human author here on Stack Overflow when answering a question, but it's something I've seen ChatGPT do a number of times.

Comment: For clarity, I don't believe you've come out and said flat-out that you *haven't* used GPT for any of your answers. It seems that you used wording that avoids the issue and made the point that you are writing in areas where you have expertise, which (as I've said) I do see and agree with. As I've also said, I hope we get to the point where this usage is considered acceptable here on SO, at least when handled appropriately (including citation of the AI).  For now, however, I'm using GPT tools personally, but avoiding their use when answering questions here on SE sites.